# Pragma and Cache Control header

Tags: caching, http-headers, httpresponse

I have response header `Cache-Control : public, max-age=53467` along with `Pragma : no-cache`.

Does that cache the web page?

My understanding is that older web browsers where Cache Control not works Pragma take the priority and not cache the page.. And in modern browsers following HTTP1.1 standards Cache-Control takes priority, cache the page and pragma gets ignore, If present.

Just looking some expert opinion in this use-case.

Thanks